# Silverlight 5 Backward Compatibility

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight application developed with version 4.0.  I tried running it with Silverlight 5 client and everything seems to be fine up to now.

But I am wondering; if my users installs Silverlight 5 for client, is it sure my application will still work well?  Do I have to run all my Test Cases again?

If anyone notices something that has been broke between versions, please list it here! :)

Thanks

Comment: All future versions should be backwards compatible. I highly doubt your application will stop working under Silverlight 5 when it was developed under Silverlight 4.

Comment: I think I've just found one such backward compatibility issue. Here's my SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974957/silverlight-5-oob-install-update-broken-when-using-anti-cache-trick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's little evidence around the internet at the moment, other than that published by Microsoft, which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg986858%28VS.96%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh397894%28v=VS.96%29.aspx), which states, to summarise:

> Several changes have been made to the Silverlight runtime and the
>   Silverlight Tools between Silverlight 4 and Silverlight 5. For these
>   changes, the following principles apply:
>
> - Most Silverlight 4 applications will work with Silverlight 5 without
>     any changes.
> - When breaking changes are required, Silverlight will try to maintain
>     support for the old behavior, as well as the new behavior, by using a
>     quirks mode.
>
> Nevertheless, some changes made to Silverlight components can
>   potentially cause your older Silverlight-based applications to fail
>   (compile time, XAML load time, or possibly design time) or to behave
>   differently.

And,

> There are no known breaking changes between Silverlight 4 and
>   Silverlight 5 in the Silverlight core runtime. Applications that were originally compiled using Silverlight 4 tools, and that continue to target the Silverlight 4 runtime, should work without issues on a client that has the Silverlight 5 runtime.
>
> If your project references any Silverlight SDK client assemblies [...] make sure that your project
>   specifically references the Silverlight 5 version of the SDK client
>   assemblies [...]. A project that targets Silverlight 5 cannot use the Silverlight
>   4 SDK assemblies.

There's more information in the links I provide, for instance, related to *quirks mode*, third party references, and behavioural changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with a Silverlight 4 tool used to display a barchart etc. The Project upgrade to VS2013 automatically upgraded to Silverlight 5 and there were no warnings. I worked on other areas of the project and only by chance did I actually run it in debug mode to find that the display was broken somewhere inside the tool. I managed to scamper back to VS2012 and scavenge the changes I had made in the VS2013 version of the project.